# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a `Location` entity which has a property of type `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint` in Spring boot and spring-data-elasticsearch project as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "location")
public class Location implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "country", nullable = false)
    private String country;

    @GeoPointField
    private GeoPoint location;
...
```

But hibernate throws `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint` when I start the application. Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `String` representation of the coordinates in the form`"12.14, 34.53"`(more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-geo-point-type.html)) with `@GeoPointField` annotation and that worked.

```
@GeoPointField
private String location;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own Location Class with two fields and use that

```
public class Location {
    private double lat; 
    private double lon; 

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }
    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
    public double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }
    public void setLon(double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }
}
```

and in your Document class you can use like this

```
    @GeoPointField
    private Location lastLocation;
```